# Gradient of a Lagrange dual function

Tags: convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, duality-theorems, subgradient

Consider:  $$\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} f(x)$$
$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{s.t. }\  h(x) \leq 0$$

1. Lagrangian:$\ \ \  L(x,\lambda) = f(x) + \lambda h(x)$
2. Suppose $x^* = \arg\min_{x} L(x,\lambda)$
3. Suppose Lagrange dual function $g(\lambda) = \inf_x L(x,\lambda)$
4. **Suppose $f,h$ are all convex function.**

> Is it true: $\ \ \ \nabla _\lambda(g(\lambda)) = h(x^*)$

Obviously $x$ is a function of $\lambda$, so $x(\lambda)$.

Next, consider an simple example:

$$\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}} x^Tx$$
$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{s.t. }\  Ax \leq b$$
1. $x^* =\arg\{\nabla_x L(x,\lambda)\} =  -\frac{1}{2}A^T\lambda$
2. $h(x^*) = -\frac{1}{2}AA^T\lambda - b$
3. $\nabla_\lambda(g(\lambda))  = -\frac{1}{2}AA^T\lambda - b$

Clearly, the equality holds in this example. However, does this equality alwayls hold?

Comment: I don't even think it's always true that $g$ is differentiable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the differentiability of the dual function $g(\lambda)$, here is a sufficient condition (See Lemma 6.3.2, Theorem 6.3.3 and Theorem 6.3.4 of Bazaraa et al. 's Nonlinear Programming: Theory and Algorithms, 2006).

Let the domain $X$ be a nonempty compact set in $R^n$, and $f$ and $h$ be continuous. For any $\lambda$, if the minimizer of $L(x, \lambda)$ is unique (say, $x^*$), then the dual function $g$ is differentiable at $\lambda$ with $\nabla g(\lambda) = h(x^*)$. Otherwise, if the minimizer of $L(x, \lambda)$ is not unique (but nonempty), then $g$ is only subdifferentiable and any $\tilde{x} \in \arg \min_x L(x, \lambda)$ yields a subgradient of $g$ at $\lambda$: $h(\tilde{x}) \in \partial g(\lambda)$.

Comment: Very nice and helpful !